# Understanding about summation in the given expression

Tags: matrices, summation, vectors, signal-processing

In my research work, I came across the following expression:

$$ \textbf{S}_c = \sum_{k = 1}^K \textbf{H}_k \textbf{p}_c \textbf{u}_k + \textbf{V}_c$$

where dimension of $\textbf{V}_c$ is $M \times L$, dimension of product of $\textbf{H}_k \textbf{p}_c \textbf{u}_k$ is $ M \times L $ and hence dimension of $ \textbf{S}_c$ is $ M \times L $.

Although, I had derived how these dimensions are coming, I am not getting exactly what role summation is performing in above expression.

Any help in this regard will highly appreciated.

Comment: $V_c$ is not part of the sum. Maybe write it like $V_c+\sum\ldots$. It would help if you could write what the matrices $H_k, p_c,u_k$ are. It looks like for every $k\in\{1,\ldots,K\}$, $H_kp_cu_k$ is of a $M\times L$ matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your response.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Sir, your understanding regarding "It looks like ....." statement is very correct.

Comment: Alright. I am glad to be of help. Does this clear up your confusion?

Comment: What do you mean by "what role summation is performing"?

Comment: @ShyamalSayak, yes sir... it has clear my confusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the right-hand side we have a sum of $K+1$ terms, each an $(M\times L)$-matrix. We have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{S}_c&= \sum_{k = 1}^K \textbf{H}_k \textbf{p}_c \textbf{u}_k + \textbf{V}_c\\
&=\textbf{H}_1 \textbf{p}_c \textbf{u}_1 +
\textbf{H}_2 \textbf{p}_c \textbf{u}_2 +
\cdots+\textbf{H}_K \textbf{p}_c \textbf{u}_K +\textbf{V}_c
\end{align*}